# Items em níveis dentro de um ComboBox em HTML. É Possível?

Tags: html, combobox

Vamos dizer que queira listar num *ComboBox* itens a venda em um site e-commerce. Mas nessa lista, quero que primeiro seja exibido o nome da categoria e abaixo os itens.
Exemplo:

- **Esportes**
- Bicicleta
- Chuteira
- **Decoração**
- Tapete
- Cortina

Mas bom seria ainda até conseguir indentar os itens. Mais ou menos como na gravura a seguir:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
É possível? Como?

Comment: Vc está usando Bootstrap?

Comment: Não, tenho pouco conhecimento na área.. apenas manutenção básica

Comment: Ok, só pra saber mesmo, então creio que qq uma das respostas abaixo vai de atender.

Comment: Caso você queira fazer algo mais personalizado: [Materialize CSS](http://materializecss.com/select.html) (simples e fácil de usar)

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Muito legal! Não conhecia... é uma biblioteca, certo? É free?

Comment: Sim é uma biblioteca free, baseada no [Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso vc tem que usar o `<optgroup>` dentro do `<select>`

Veja o exemplo:

```html
<select>
    <optgroup label="Category 1">
        <option>Item 1</option>
        <option>Item 2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Category 2">
        <option>Item 3</option>
        <option>Item 4</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Referência: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```